# Python-Numpy: How to get summary of a certain part of rows in a column? (cumulative summary)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
Volume  Weight
1   6
2   7
3   8
4   9
5   10
```

For example, I have a 5 by 2 matrix data.

**What I want to do is:**

> 1.For each row in weight column, calculate the summary from that row all the way down to the bottom (row 5, column 2)

> 2.Then I can get a cumulative summary column like this

```
Volume  Weight  Cumulative Weight
1   6   40
2   7   34
3   8   27
4   9   19
5   10  10
```

I know we can use a combination of for loops, but is there some silver bullets to solve this problem? I.e, some numpy/panda methods?

Comment: `df[::-1, 'Weight'].cumsum()`. Please don't put images when data is copy-pastable reproducing your data would be tedious. Use `df.to_clipboard()` to copy your df to clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) on the reversed Series:

```
df['Cumulative Weight'] = df.loc[::-1, 'Weight'].cumsum()
```

Output:

```
   Volume  Weight  Cumulative Weight
0       1       6                 40
1       2       7                 34
2       3       8                 27
3       4       9                 19
4       5      10                 10
```